# Difference between present and past simple after 'suggested that'

Tags: past-simple, present-simple, sequence-of-tenses

These are the sentences that I found in Cambridge grammar books:

> I **suggested** that she **bought** a car.
>   I **suggested** that he **gives up** golf.

Both of the sentences above start in the past simple but end in the **past simple** and **present simple** respectively. Why is that and what's the difference in meaning?

UPDATE: Now that I'm thinking about it, I have a guess about the differences between these two:

"I suggested that she **bought** a car" means:

> I suggested that she bought a car but at the moment it's not clear whether she has bought it.

"I suggested that he **gives up** golf" means:

> I suggested that he **gives up** golf but he hasn't given up it yet. Perhaps later. Or never.

Though I'm not sure about it and need someone to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I interpret these sentences:

> I **suggested** that she **bought** a car

This would be equivalent to "I gave the impression that she bought a car [even if that wasn't the truth]." In this case the speaker was not addressing the presumed buyer of the car ("she") while doing the suggesting.

> I **suggested** that he gives up golf.

I think this is a less formal/"correct" way of saying "I suggested that he **give** up golf" - meaning "I told him [or someone else] that he should give up golf." (Normally the present subjunctive uses a bare infinitive form of the verb.) The speaker may or may not have addressed the other person ("he") while doing the suggesting.

EDIT: For sentence 2, I am now not sure that thinking of the suggestion as possibly being directed towards the other person ("he") actually makes sense. The meaning of "to suggest" that makes sense to me in both sentences is "to imply as a possibility" (to anybody, not necessarily the "he" or "she" spoken about) rather than "to advise" (where the "he" or "she" is the recipient of the advice). This way, the subjunctive mood isn't required, and the sentences do not sound ungrammatical. The second sentence therefore would have a meaning more like "I *implied* that he gives up golf [on occasion; whenever someone tells him to; etc.]"

EDIT 2: I have learned from the OP that the rules concerning use of the subjunctive are different in British English from (my native) American English. The original sentences are in fact valid expressions of the act of giving advice. If you're talking to an American audience, you might be met with confusion, but if the audience is British then I suggest you leave the sentences be. (see what I did there? :-p)

Comment: Alright. Interesting. Thank you. Just several minutes before you posted this answer I updated my question with my own guess. What do you think of it? Does it make sense?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the update before posting my answer. I hate to say this, but I am not completely sure what you are getting at when you use the same original sentences in the respective longer sentences. Could you replace the word "suggested" with something equivalent in each explanation?

Comment: Realized I was being slightly hypocritical there - edited my answer to hopefully be more clear about what I think the "suggested" part means in each case. I think knowing who the person is who is the recipient of the suggesting is important to understanding the meaning.

Comment: I think I do understand your answer. I'm just talking about a bit different aspect. I guess that when we use the present simple after 'I suggested that' then we refer to the future and not the past. For example:"I suggested that she **buys** a car and a day later she bought it.". I guess this sentence makes no sense because the suggestion is still relevant, so she couldn't have bought a car yet. But I think that it's perfectly correct to say: "I suggested that she bought a car and a day later she **bought** it." So, does my understanding make any sense?

Comment: @Karolini hmm. This sentence sounds fine to me: "I suggested that she **buy** a car and a day later she bought it." This sentence says that "she" bought the car a day after I gave her the suggestion to do so. I still think "buys" sounds weird as it is not the correct subjunctive form, and I would not say this same sentence with **buys** in place of **buy** for that reason. And I think I disagree with you about the meaning of the second sentence. "I suggested that she bought a car" to me can only make sense if the suggestion is not directed at *her* (whoever *she* is).

Comment: @Karolini I just edited my answer again. I am now rejecting the idea that there is any subjunctive involved in either sentence. I believe the only meaning of "to suggest" that makes sense in both cases is "to imply", not "to recommend/advise". I hope that makes sense.

Comment: My book says "I suggested that she **buy** a car" and "I suggested that she **bought** a car" are similar in meaning. But I think I've found some explanation on Wikipedia: "dual statement/directive use of verbs like **insist**, **suggest** and **propose** can lead to confusion in cases where some, mainly British, speakers informally use the indicative and not the subjunctive, strongly preferred by many, especially Americans". It also gives an example sentence: "He worked in an optical business off Baker Street, and I suggested that he studied lenses and optics, and got him into night school".

Comment: @Karolini wow, ok! You got me, I am an American, and using the indicative in place of the subjunctive just sounds strange to me. Therefore, if you're learning British English (as I assume if you're using Cambridge books) you should disregard my point of view. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why that is, but I can try to explain the differences:

1. "I **suggested** that she **bought** a car." --- Imagine a version of this in dialogue between two people:

> Andy: What did you tell her to do?
>
> Bob: I had suggested that she should buy a car. `(The example sentence
>   is another way to say this)`
>
> Andy: Cool. So is she going to buy one?
>
> Bob: Yep!

---

2. I **suggested** that he **gives up** golf. --- I'm not sure that this one is gramatically correct. Since you have the word **suggested** there ought to be the word **should** as well. Here it is in an example:

> Amanda: What did you say to him?
>
> Britt: I suggested that he *should* give up golf.
>
> Amanda: But why? I thought he loved playing golf.
>
> Britt: Nah. It stresses him out to run into his boss at the country
>   club. He should take a break from it.

Comment: Thank you! I know that we can use 'should' as well as subjunctive mood in both of the sentences, but my question is specifically about the difference between the present and past simple in these sentences. As both of the sentences are from Cambridge grammar books, I assume that they are grammatically correct.