# Its important he reads this

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Saw a movie today and there was a guy who said

> It's important he reads this.

Its beautiful and confusing to me at the same time. What's the grammar structure behind this sentence? Where I can read more about this so I can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the subjunctive mood, as @sbutkovi says. The more "correct" way to use the subjunctive mood would be to say "It's important **[that]** he **read** this" - where *read* is the bare infinitive, not conjugated for the third person singular, as it would be in the indicative mood.

Comment: Thank you! But why the guy said 'reads' instead of read?

Comment: Not everyone obeys all the rules of "correct" English all the time, even if they are native speakers. What movie is this from, out of curiosity? Do you have a clip?

Comment: BTW - I know "Boy Erased" is an American movie, but apparently it is more common in British English to use the indicative in place of the subjunctive - which is what's happening here. See a related discussion here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/196357/difference-between-present-and-past-simple-after-suggested-that/196393

Answer (score 0):

"It's important he reads this" is an example of the subjunctive mood, which can be read about more here:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive
https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/the-subjunctive
https://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/

In general, the subjunctive mood is used to discuss things in a hypothetical or uncertain sense.